# How can I send username and password with axios request

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3

I am calling a get request on BambooHr API like this:

```
  axios.get
   (`https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/2223/photo/large`
    ).then((res)=> {
          console.log("response ",res)
        });
    },
```

I have API key and password. How can I send it along with my get request. In the api they are showing like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/employeeId/photo/size',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
};

axios
  .request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

In place of "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" there is Api key and passwords encoded value is coming. So how can I do this my code. And while trying some things I am getting cors errors as well

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
await axios.get(session_url, {
  auth: {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
});
```

It will should get encoded into the basic format by itself.

If that did not work here is an alternative:

```js
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
axios.get(session_url, {
  headers: { 'Authorization': + basicAuth }
})
```

In your exact case this means changing options to this:

```js
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/employeeId/photo/size',
    auth: {
       username: "username",
       password: "password"
    }
};
```

or this:

```js
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/employeeId/photo/size',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(username + ':' + password)}`
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes I tried this now, But I am not able to check the response because of cors error. It is saying access to XMLHttpReq at "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/2223/photo/large" from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by cors policy @MalwareMoon

Comment: @user20042604 That's completely unrelated to the problem this tho. You probably need to add your page to the CORS list for that API.

Comment: If I am giving responseType on this as blob. Then it is giving me 401 error in vuejs. But same thing I have tried in react it is giving me response. Any idea on this?

Comment: @user20042604 If that only is when you change response type, but works otherwise, I am not sure to be honest. I don't think you can just tell server to serve it in however format you want at it will work (unless this is supported).

Comment: with responseType as blob it is giving 401 error but luckily I found img url in that api response itself which is working. So now I don't need to pass responsetype because that link did the work for me. Thanks for help.